# Is it ok to access data using cast when I am not sure about alignment

Tags: c, arm

consider a page that was read from somewhere. I want to compare a value at an offset in that page to a 4 bytes integer. Is the following code going to work on ARM as well as on X86?

```
bool equal(char *page, uint32 offset, uint32 data)
{
    return *(uint32 *) (page+offset) == data;
}
```

Or do I need to memcpy 4 bytes from offset to a uint32 variable first?

Comment: It depends on where `page` points at. This could be a misaligned access or a strict aliasing violation both.

Comment: Alignment requirements are determined by the C implementation, not by the target architecture. A compiler and an operating system might or might not support unaligned accesses, and that can depend on switches given to the compiler or modes set in the processor. I have used compilers and operating systems which did support unaligned accesses and compilers and operating systems which did not. Further, the code shown also apparently does not conform to the aliasing rules in the C standard. Whether that is supported is also a property of the compiler, not the target architecture.

Comment: From the alignment perspective, it would depend also on what ARM it is and what the options are. On ARMv7 for example it is possible to allow/disallow unaligned access in the control registers.

Comment: Re “Or do I need to `memcpy` 4 bytes from offset to a uint32 variable first?”: If your `uint32` is 32 bits in size (no padding), then `return 0 == memcmp(page+offset, &data, sizeof data);` suffices.

Comment: Or just remove this pointless function and call `memcmp(&page[offset], &(uint32_t){data}, 4);` directly...

Comment: @EricPostpischil The architecture can either support or not. And the compiler should know it to generate the appropriate memory access instructions for the unaligned accesses (like leave it to the machine to deal with or handle it on the compiler level). Here is an article about it https://medium.com/@iLevex/the-curious-case-of-unaligned-access-on-arm-5dd0ebe24965

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I am aware ARM may or may not support aligned access. What does that have to do with what I wrote?

Comment: @EricPostpischil "Alignment requirements are determined by the C implementation, not by the target architecture." - I interpret it as a claim that alignment requirements are not depending on the architecture.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Indeed, alignment requirements are **not** dependent on the architecture. A compiler can support accesses that are unaligned (according to hardware operations). When generating assembly for accesses that the compiler does not know are definitely aligned, the compiler would then generate whatever instructions are necessary to perform the access. That can be using “load unaligned” instructions or using multiple “load aligned” instructions combined with shifts to assemble the necessary bytes. For example, GCC supports this with its “packed” attribute.

Answer (score 4):

As you suspect, it is not safe to access data via a potentially unaligned pointer.  It has undefined behavior and depending on the target CPU, it may work as expected (x86) or throw a Bus error (most other CPUs).

You can make your code portable using `memcpy` or `memcmp` as follows:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

bool equal(const char *page, size_t offset, uint32_t data) {
    uint32_t v;
    memcpy(&v, page + offset, sizeof v);
    return v == data;
}

bool equal2(const char *page, size_t offset, uint32_t data) {
    return !memcmp(page + offset, &data, sizeof data);
}
```

It is recommended to write portable code using the appropriate types (`size_t` for offset improves code generation) and let the compile do the optimisation.

As can bee verified on [Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8Yjoa5KE4), the above code does compile to optimal code for `equal` on both x86 and ARM targets, using the appropriate load instructions.

The alternative using `memcmp` suggested in comments seems more complicated for both `gcc` and `clang` to optimize fully. Also note that the `memcmp` approach would not work in all cases for other scalar types: for example IEEE `float` and `double` types have 2 distinct representations for positive and negative zero, which would compare equal for `==` but not for `memcmp` in a version of the above code for `float` or `double` typed `data`. Other scalar types in exotic architectures might also have multiple representations or even have padding bits with the same shortcomings. Using `memcpy` seems preferable.

Comment: The `memcpy` version also has the advantage that it works for scalar types that have padding bits or multiple bit representations of a value. (That doesn't apply to exact-width integer types.)

Comment: @IanAbbott: good point, I shall amend the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

No, it's not "safe". An UltraSPARC CPU will send you a "Bus Error" when trying this unaligned, for example.
And you didn't took care about endianness, too - it MAY be a problem too, depending from where the data come from.

You should guard your code with a generic, "slow" decoder (byte per byte, with shifting and endianness-aware code), and then a "fast" decoder enabled **ONLY** for CPU you know for accepting such accesses.

For example, for MSVC, a x86 compilation will have the `_M_IX86` macro defined, so you can do something like:

```cpp
// Default: do not allow unaligned access
#undef USE_UNALIGNED
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #ifdef _M_IX86
    // For this compiler+CPU, OK, using unaligned is allowed.
    #define USE_UNALIGNED
  #endif
#endif

....

bool equal(char *page, uint32 offset, uint32 data)
{
#ifdef USE_UNALIGNED
    // Fast / unaligned method.
    return *(uint32 *) (page+offset) == data;
#else
    // Slow/byte per byte method.
#endif
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243407/discussion-on-answer-by-wisblade-is-it-ok-to-access-data-using-cast-when-i-am-no).